# Any JSR 227 implementations other than ADFm?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I am just curious and was not able to find anything from Google.

Is there any other implementation of JSR 227? It seems the only implementation for it is from Oracle namely ADFm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct - Oracle ADF is the only framework that implemented this JSR.
By the way this is no longer being promoted as a JSR.

`Withdrawn as of 02 May, 2011`

Comment: Ah! my bad reading.. I re-read the JSR details to verify you claim of the JSR being withdrawn! :) Thanks for the info